# With Android gradle plugin 3.1.0 is it still best to manually specify the android build tools?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In release 3.1.0 of the Android gradle plugin release notes (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) Google writes that the plugin requires:

> Build Tools 27.0.3 or higher. Keep in mind, you no longer need to
>   specify a version for the build tools using the
>   android.buildToolsVersion property—the plugin uses the minimum
>   required version by default.

It says it will auto-select the "minimum". So what happens if a fix or improvement is released to the android tools? For example the minimum is 27.0.3 but 28.0.2 has been released with a new version of D8 that may have fixes or improvements but the plugin will continue using 27.0.3 if not otherwise specified so it still seems best to manually select the build tools as needed so you aren't stuck on the minimum version required?

Comment: That's the **minimum required version** for the current `gradle` which means it uses the minimum version of `27.0.3` and higher and if there would be a new update, Android Studio will let you know or ask to see if you wanna update or not! (*If this is what you're asking tho*)

Answer (score 1):

It's the minimum required version, you can keep it as it is now but it's highly recommended to update to the newest version.